# Cleanest way of implementing conditional view logic in an application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, architecture

I'm designing an application where a user will select from a list of products and add them to a shopping cart. Services will be presented to the user grouped together by category.

The same list of products and categories are not always shown. They can change day to day.

This is all fine, the tricky part is that there are a select number of categories, that when shown, need to alter the behavior of the application slightly.

For example, lets say we have 3 categories, Category A, B and C.
Any time category B is shown then it must appear on screen above category A.
Any time a user selects a product from category B then they must also select a product from category C.
None of these rules apply if category B is not shown.

One thing to note is that the list of services and categories come from a third party web service so there is very little scope to add or change database columns.

What is the cleanest way of implementing this kind of logic?

Answer (score 1):

Most of this can be sorted out in the controller or model.

So: the logic about which categories to display above which other categories is just a sort-order on the categories yes? So you could keep a "sort column" on the Category model and sort them by this field.

The "must select one of these if one of those is selected" is more tricky - but definitely a model-based validation. I presume you've got some kind of "order" model to keep together the things that a user has put in their shopping basket?
Add a validation method that goes something like:

```
validate :product_b_and_product_c

def product_b_and_product_c
  if self.products.any? {|p| p.category == 'category_b' }
    errors.add_to_base "must choose product from cat C if you have one in cat B" unless self.products.any? {p| p.category == 'category_c' }
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One thing I didn't mention is that the categories and services are coming from a third party rest service so it's not possible for me to add a new db column. I've updated the question to say this.

Comment: ok, so that affects sorting... you can indeed put logic into the view (or preferably the controller) to affect sorting post fetch, if you need it. How about the validation above though?